# HTML-Box for WordPress Navigation

Tags: wordpress, navigation, child-theming

Is there a way to enable a HTML-Box to include into the navigation for WordPress Backend (Appearance > Menu)? Reason is, I would like to include images/videos etc.

I couldnt find any Solution in the internet. And I dont want to use another plugin as its bad for the speed-performance.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to add HTML code in WordPress default navigation. If you are more advanced developer you can use WordPress Navigation Walker to overwrite default navigation HTML. [WP Navigation Walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker)